# Codeigniter sessions in firefox won't set

Tags: codeigniter, session, firefox

I'm using [Codeigniter](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter)'s session class to create cookies and store session info in my database, but I'm running into issues across browsers.
It seems I've got everything working now for all browsers except **Firefox**. The site keeps kicking users out immediately after they log in.  My suspicion is that for some reason the session never gets set.

Any advise?
Website here: http://www.nanp.org.
Code below:

```
public function post() {
   $this->load->model('rbac/user');
   if($user = $this->user->user_by_column(array('email'=>$_POST['email'],'password'=>$_POST['password'],'verified'=>'true'))) {
      $this->session->set_userdata(array('user_id'=>$user->user_id));
      if($_POST['redirect']!='') {header('Location:'.$_POST['redirect']);}
      else {header('Location:members/dashboard');}
   }
   else {
      $this->data['php_error'] = 'Incorrect email or password.';
   }
}
```

This is my session config info:

```
$config['sess_cookie_name']     = 'nanpsession';
$config['sess_expiration']      = 2628000;
$config['sess_expire_on_close'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_encrypt_cookie']  = TRUE;
$config['sess_use_database']    = TRUE;
$config['sess_table_name']      = 'ci_sessions';
$config['sess_match_ip']        = FALSE;
$config['sess_match_useragent'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_time_to_update']  = 300;

$config['cookie_prefix']    = "";
$config['cookie_domain']    = "";
$config['cookie_path']      = "/";
$config['cookie_secure']    = FALSE;
```

Answer (score 1):

try with `2 equal signs` for the if statement :

```
 public function post() {
   $this->load->model('rbac/user');
   if($user == $this->user->user_by_column(array('email'=>$_POST['email'],'password'=>$_POST['password'],'verified'=>'true'))) {
     $this->session->set_userdata(array('user_id'=>$user->user_id));
     if($_POST['redirect']!='') {header('Location:'.$_POST['redirect']);}
     else {header('Location:members/dashboard');}
   }
   else {
    $this->data['php_error'] = 'Incorrect email or password.';
   }
}
```

More information about the meaning of one equal on a PHP If Statment here : [A php if statement with one equal sign...? What does this mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1518076/a-php-if-statement-with-one-equal-sign-what-does-this-mean)

Comment: Don't think that's my issue. I'm not checking for equality there, and that's not a browser issue, that's a PHP issue, so if that were the problem it would be showing up for all browsers, not just firefox.

Answer (score 1):

How can you confirm the session is not working. Try printing any session variable or echo this, if this returns empty array, then your session might not be working.

```
 echo  print_r($this->session->set_userdata());
```

Since you are saying your session is terminated on **Firefox** only, might be you have configured something on Firefox because of which its resetting the session variables.

Comment: Yes, I have been printing session data right after the "set_userdata" line. For some Firefox users the "userdata" key of Codeigniter's session array is empty. Funny thing is, everything works fine for me using Firefox - other users are having the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed Firebug? It could cause the problem. Please refer to [Firebug destroying session variables in Codeigniter application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12364775/firebug-destroying-session-variables-in-codeigniter-application).